# How to boot UEFI image from PXE?

Tags: uefi, pxe

I would like to load Memtest86 image file from PXE. Unfortunately, [their ISO file on site contains old version](http://www.memtest86.com/downloads/memtest86-iso.zip) of Memtest, which load automatically with this config:

```
DEFAULT menu.c32
PROMPT 0
#MENU BACKGROUND moon800.jpg
#MENU RESOLUTION 800 600
#MENU MARGIN 20

MENU TITLE In The Moon Network

LABEL memtest
MENU LABEL Memtest86 7.3
KERNEL memdisk
INITRD /iso/Memtest86-7.3.iso
APPEND iso raw
...
```

Is it possible to boot this image as UEFI?

Comment: That iso contains `EFI/BOOT/BOOTX64.EFI` and `EFI/BOOT/BOOTIA32.EFI` files which in theory could be pointed at by appropriate DHCP server configuration statements plus a TFTP server...

Answer (score 1):

As of Version 7 of Memtest, they officially support PXE boot with their  Site License. https://www.memtest86.com/tech_pxe-network.html

So you won't be able to boot the image using PXE without purchasing the licence.